# About Customize Data Table

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, datatables

I am having some following strange requirement:

1.Only 5 records to load by default on mobile site with paginated data to load in subsequent pages.

and

2.In desktop view load by default 10 records with paginated data to load in subsequent pages.

Mobile site is not in format of  "m.".
So is there any way to change the data table and load the data in that as per the desktop and mobile view.

P.S: It's predefined theme so I will not able to use bootstrap. Only HTML,JQuery and CSS can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the width of the screen on load, and then draw the datatable instance as per the needed row per page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //initilise your datatable
        var myDtInstance=$('#datatable').DataTable( {
            "lengthMenu": [ 5,10, 20], //set required length menu
            "pageLength": 10 //set your default page length
        });
        windowSize = $(window).width(); //get your current window width
        //call function which will set the page length as per window size
        manipulateDataTableLen(5,10,myDtInstance);
        //this will called everytime window get resized
        $(window).resize(function(){
            manipulateDataTableLen(5,10,test);
        });
    });
    function manipulateDataTableLen(rowSize,defaultSize,dtInstance){
        windowSize = $(window).width();
        if(windowSize<=PUT_DESIRED_WINDOW_SIZE){
            dtInstance.page.len(rowSize).draw(false);
        }else{
            dtInstance.page.len(defaultSize).draw(false);
        }
    }
<script>
```